# How to implement Blowfish algorithm in J2ME?

Tags: java-me, blowfish

> 

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
```

are these not included in J2ME?
Then How can I implement the blowfish algorithm in J2ME?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [The Legion of the Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html), a set of open source cryptography APIs that includes Java ME (J2ME) support.